# Windows 2012 Server inaccessible (using rdp) but SQL Server databases are accessible (ssms)

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, sql-server-2012, ssrs

We have a Windows Server 2012 Standard, which runs SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition. This morning we found the reporting services was inaccessible. We attempted to use Remote Desktop to connect to the machine, but could not get in. All databases were accessible via SSMS and other apps. Eventually we restarted the machine around 9AM.

The strange thing is when we restarted it we checked the windows event logs and found this entry

```
The previous system shutdown at 8:47:38 PM on ‎11/‎7/‎2017 was unexpected.
```

even though the machine was running until 9AM. There are no other entries between 8:47PM 11/7/2017 and 9:00AM 11/8/2017.

As a side note, DBCC checkDB was running from 8:00PM till 11:11PM.

Do these symptoms point to anything specific?

Where can I look for more information as to what caused the crash?

Are there any perf monitor counters that might help if this happens again?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a power failure and your server wasnt still ready for RDP yet at 9, but SQL was up. RDP access start late in the service order.

Please check in the server management log to see a cause. (DRAC,iLO,etc..)

While in the management validate that no other error is found, like for RAM.